# Normal distribution - values are recorded to the nearest 10th of a kilogram problem

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I am having problems with understanding the solution to the following exercise, which is as follows:

> The weights of a large number of miniature poo-
>   dles are approximately normally distributed with a
>   mean of 8 kilograms and a standard deviation of 0.9
>   kilogram. If measurements are recorded to the nearest
>   tenth of a kilogram, find the fraction of these poodles
>   with weights
>   (a) over 9.5 kilograms;
>   (b) of at most 8.6 kilograms;
>   (c) between 7.3 and 9.1 kilograms inclusive

now, the solution is:

(a)  $ = P(X >
9.55) = P(Z > 1.72) = 0.0427. $

(b)  $ = P(X <
8.65) = P(Z < 0.72) = 0.7642. $

(c)
 $= P(7.25 < X < 9.15) = P(−0.83 < Z < 1.28) = 0.8997 − 0.2033 = 0.6964. $

Now, I have successfully completed the exercise a). The exercise said that the measurements are recorded to the nearest *tenth* of a kilogram. What I did in a) was add half a kilogram to 9.5 which gives us 9.55 because it's the first higher value (>) which is recorded

However, in b) my solution was

b) $P(X≤8.6)$,

and in

c) $P(7.25 ≤ X ≤ 9.00).$

My method was to add half a kilogram to the x value whenever the sign was "greater or equal to", and to subtract half a kilogram from the x value whenever the sign was "less or equal to".

Obviously my "trick" did not work in those two exercises and I have no clue why. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question, but I *think* I understand what is going on. So question (b) is a little bit confusing because it says 'at most $8.6$ kilograms'. However, if a poodle weighs $8.64$ kg, then they would fall into this category. Essentially, because the margin of error is $\pm 0.05$, we cannot say $8.64$ is too large in this context. Thus, you should compute $P(X < 8.65)$ (or, equivalently $P(X \leq 8.65)$.

Comment: @Joe Sorry for the poor wording. 

My question essentially was how to I determine the "x" value. For example, question (c) is between 7.3 and 9.1 kilograms. Why is it suddenly  (7.25 < X <9.15) in the solution? What do I do when I'm given the margin of error (like I am given here)? Thanks!

Comment: OK let's imagine that you knew the weight of the poodles exactly (with no margin of error whatsoever). Then, you round all of these answers to the nearest tenth. If a poodle has weight, $x$, and $7.25 \leq x < 9.15$, then $x$ would round to a number within the range you just described: between $7.3$ and $9.1$. More concretely, $x$ would round to one of the following numbers: $\{7.3,7.4,7.5,7.6,\cdots,8.8,8.9,9.0, 9.1\}$. We therefore call $7.25$ and $9.15$ the *lower and upper bounds*, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to conceptualize the model here is to think of two random variables, say $Y$, which is the weighed value to the nearest $0.1$ kg, and the true value $X$, which is not observable due to the limited instrument precision.  So if $Y = 8.2$ kg observed, this means that $X$ is some value in the interval $[8.15, 8.25)$.

Then what we are given is that $$X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = 8, \sigma = 0.9),$$ not $Y$, because the latter is a rounded value, thus it is not possible to observe $Y = 8.2353$, for example.  You'd observe $Y = 8.2$ instead.

We are asked in Part (a) to compute $\Pr[Y > 9.5]$ the probability of poodles whose observed weights exceed $9.5$ kg.  This of course must correspond to $\Pr[X \ge 9.55]$, and since the outcome $X = 9.55$ has measure zero, this is equivalent to computing $\Pr[X > 9.55]$.  The other parts of the question are handled similarly.

---

Your reasoning in Part (a) doesn't make sense.  $9.55$ is not the next "half-kilogram" value exceeding $9.5$.  Half a kilogram would be $0.5$, thus $9.5 + 0.5 = 10$.  If you instead meant the next $0.05$ kilogram--i.e., a *twentieth* of a kilogram, then you have to justify why this works; e.g., why add instead of subtract.  This part of your reasoning is what is flawed.

To understand the relationship between the desired probability for $Y$ and the corresponding set of outcomes for $X$, all one needs to do is think about what $X$-values will round to a $Y$-value that satisfies the inequality.  For example, if we want $$\Pr[8.3 \le Y < 9.2],$$ then the smallest $X$-value that rounds up to $Y = 8.3$ is $X = 8.25$.  The largest $X$-value that rounds down to $Y = 9.1$ is $X = 9.15$ (technically there is no supremum but any number less than $9.15$ results in $Y \le 9.1$).  The key here is that if the inequality for $Y$ is strict--for instance, $Y < 9.2$, then because $Y$ is discrete, we can't observe $Y = 9.199999$; thus $$Y < 9.2 \iff Y \le 9.1.$$  Then we find the biggest $X$ that rounds down to this value.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's bad wording on my part, I didn't mean half a kilogram but half the margin of error that was given which is 0.05. I was not sure why it worked for question (a) (it was a hard game of guessing for me, we hadn't gone through this at university).

I understand now! Thanks again!